# Recommendation for NVCC compatible minimal c++ matrix library for unit test

Tags: c++

I am developing a templated CUDA matrix libraries, which means I have put the implementation in the same file as the headers. This is all good except this makes unit testing quite annoying. I want to test some simple functionalities such addition and basic matrix decomposition (wrapping cuSolver) by comparing the results with CPU based matrix libraries. However, I use to use Eigen, but NVCC cannot handle it.

I am looking for a minimal C++ CPU based matrix libraries, which wraps the functionality of blas and lapack, that is compatible with NVCC. I do not require any speed, neither do I require sparse matrix support. It is good if the library does not require any external blas or lapack implementation but even if it does it is still ok.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Templating doesn't mean you have to put the implementation in the same file as the header: 1. You can have separate files and just make sure the translation unit includes both. 2. You could explicitly instantiate a bunch of implementations and then only expose the declarations to other translation units (thus limiting the possible type combinations). Just saying.

Comment: More to the point, though - don't compile all of your code with nvcc. You can very well have .o files compiled with gcc/clang and .o files compiled with nvcc linked together. This is common practice.

Comment: I understand i can explicitly instantantiate... however, in this case it is going to be very very annoying because I use tricks very similar to Eigen. For example, I have a+b return an operation representing the add operation, in order to chain the operations to facialitate lazy evaluation. If there is no other ways I will instantiate it myself, but doing so for now is quite time consuming....